# Choose two disjoint three-element sets, so the product is a set of five non-identical numbers

Tags: combinatorics

So I want to create two unordered sets $x_1=(a,b,c)$ and $x_2=(d,e,f)$ so that all possible products of a term from $x_1$ with a term of $x_2$ constitute five different numbers. The sets can't overlap and have to consist of three distinct numbers each.

I have been trying this by trial and error, and I'm not sure what kind of math I can use to solve this. With one set with only two nonidentical numbers i can do it, but the task does not allow me this.

In the title I say product of sets, Im not sure that is the right word. Above I try to describe this: {x*y for x in {1,2,3} for y in {2,3,4} if x != y}

Comment: What definition of ordered pair are you using ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory))?

Comment: If you can do this with two overlapping sets and non-zero elements, then you can eliminate the overlap by multiplying all elements in one of the sets by a very large constant.

Comment: Another idea: try to do this for sums instead of products, and then use exponentiation.

Comment: @zev, they are not ordered, I will change this in the post.

Comment: @Leo: Can you provide your definition of the product of two sets then? [Since it doesn't appear to be the standard one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Most_common_implementation_.28set_theory.29).

Comment: @dan, sorry I can do it with a set with two nonidentical numbers I meant, I changed it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward solution: Choose $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$. All numbers between $1+4=5$ and $3+6=9$ appear as sums of elements of this two sets.

Now use @DanShved's hint:
$$(2^1,2^2,2^3)=(2,4,8)$$
$$(2^4,2^5,2^6)=(16,32,64)$$

---

**EDIT:** You were asking, why this method works:

Let $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ be sets, such that there are five distinct numbers in the sums of the nine possible pairs,   and $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be an injective and multiplicative function, where *multiplicative* means $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R: f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$.

Then for $i_1,i_2,j_1,j_2\in\{1,2,3\}$:
$$a_{i_1}+b_{j_2}=a_{i_2}+b_{j_2} \Leftrightarrow f(a_{i_1}+b_{j_2})=f(a_{i_2}+b_{j_2}) \Leftrightarrow f(a_{i_1})f(b_{j_2})=f(a_{i_2})f(b_{j_2})$$
The first equivalence holds because of injectivity and the second because $f$ is multiplicative.

It follows, that there are five distinct numbers in the product of the nine possible pairs of $(f(a_1),f(a_2),f(a_3))$ and $(f(b_1),f(b_2),f(b_3))$.

In the above example, I chose $f(x)=2^x$, which is injective and multiplicative.

Comment: Thank you, this does answer my question. I still dont quite understand why this method works though.

Comment: @Leo: See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try $\{2, 4, 8\}, \{3, 6, 12\}$.

Comment: Yes this worked! Did you do this by trial and error, or is there a formal way to get this?

Comment: I did it by trial and no error.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are 9 possible pairs, we must have $4$ equations for these pairs to get $5$ different products. Assuming $a < b < c$ and $d < e < f$, the only possible set of equations are $ae = bd$, $af = be = cd$ and $bf = ce$.

From $ae = bd$ and $af = be$, we see that $\frac{d}e = \frac{e}f$. Let $\ell = \frac ed$. It follows that $e = \ell d$ and $f = \ell^2d$.

From $af = be$ and $bf = ce$, we see that $\frac ab = \frac bc$. Let $k = \frac ba$. It follows that $b = k a$ and $c = k^2 a$.

We still have not used the equation $be = cd$. Substitute everything we know, we get $(ka)(\ell d) = (k^2a)d$, so $\ell = k$.

To verify that these pieces are enough to produce the five equations, check the following:

- $ae = bd = kad$.
- $af = be = cd = k^2ad$.
- $bf = ce = k^3ad$.

Now we know that any choice of $k, a, d$ gives the 4 equations. What is left is choosing $k, a, d$ such that $\{a, ka, k^2a\}$ is disjoint from $\{d, kd, k^2d\}$. (Note that $k > 1$ is required.)

Since $a \ne d$ implies $ka \ne kd$ and $k^2a \ne k^2d$, we can disregard the last two conditions.

Similarly, $a \ne kd$ subsumes $ka \ne k^2d$, and $d \ne ka$ subsumes $kd \ne k^2a$.

We are left with only four conditions to check for $k$: $a \ne kd$, $a \ne k^2d$, $d \ne ka$ and $d \ne k^2a$.

To conclude, we can find a solution by first picking $a$ and $d$ as two unequal natural numbers, then pick $k$ according to the above four conditions. $(a, ka, k^2a)$ and $(d, kd, k^2d)$ will work. This method exhausts all solutions.

Note that if $a \not\mid d$ and $d \not\mid a$, any $k$ will work.